# handling multiple git account for different repos

Tags: github, git

I've two github accounts for different clients repositories, before I've been working with one only but trying to figure out a way to add multiple accounts on my system,

It seems to me git command line tools work under a single user email and access token, is it possible to add multiple users?

Comment: [link](https://medium.com/@pinglinh/how-to-have-2-github-accounts-on-one-machine-windows-69b5b4c5b14e) this might solve your problem

Comment: git itself does not care about GitHub accounts. The credential managers do. They saved credentials for one account and just use them by default. You could either use ssh keys (see the link in the other command) or just specify the username in the repository URL (`https://USERNAME@github.com/USER/REPO`)